# How to encrypt / decrypt data in Shiny app

Tags: r, encryption, shiny, hash, openssl

I am new to encrypting/decrypting data. I am storing in a SQL table a list of people's details and one of the columns has sensitive bank details data. This table is rendered to authorized users in a Shiny application. These users are meant to add, update and view this sensitive column only on a case-by-case basis via the Shiny app. They would click 'add' or 'edit' to update the bank details column one at a time.

I have the Shiny part and reading and writing to SQL all sorted out. What I want to achieve is when a user types in the bank details, **the encrypted value is written back to the SQL table to be saved and when they view a record in the Shiny app decrypted value is shown**.

I have written a dummy app to simulate the case:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Showing reactive table of all records
  DT::DTOutput("allrecords"),
  
  # Button to allow user to add a new record
  actionButton("add_record_bttn", "Add Record", class = "btn-primary"),
  hr(),
  
  # Form for the user to fill to save new or update existing
  uiOutput("name"),
  uiOutput("bank"),
  uiOutput("save")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  reactive_val <-
    reactiveValues(
      df_all_records = NULL
    )
  
  
  # Creating table for the sake of example. This is where I would query my SQL table
  name_col <-
    c("Bob", "Jane", "Charlie")
  bank_col <-
    c("ABC", "EDG", "HIJ")
  all_records <- data.frame(name_col, bank_col)
  reactive_val$df_all_records <-
    all_records
  
  # Rendering table
  output$allrecords <-
    DT::renderDT(
    datatable(reactive_val$df_all_records, selection = 'single', rownames = FALSE)
  )
  
  # Showing form when add button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$add_record_bttn, {
    
    output$name <-
      renderUI(textInput("nameGiven", "Enter Name:"))
    output$bank <-
      renderUI(textInput("bankGiven", "Enter Bank:"))
    output$save <-
      renderUI(actionButton("save", "Save Record", class = "btn-success"))
  })
  
  # Appending new row to the table. This is where the I'd write back to SQL table in my actual app
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    
    reactive_val$df_all_records[nrow(reactive_val$df_all_records) + 1,] <- c(input$nameGiven, input$bankGiven)
    print(reactive_val$df_all_records)
  })
  
  # Showing form when and existing record is clicked
  observeEvent(input$allrecords_rows_selected, {
    print(input$allrecords_rows_selected)
    output$name <-
      renderUI(textInput("nameGiven", "Enter Name:", value = reactive_val$df_all_records[input$allrecords_rows_selected, "name_col"]))
    output$bank <-
      renderUI(textInput("bankGiven", "Enter Bank:", value = reactive_val$df_all_records[input$allrecords_rows_selected, "bank_col"]))
    output$save <-
      renderUI(actionButton("save", "Save As New Record", class = "btn-success"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**The table looks like this now:**

[image]

**I want it to look like this:**

[image]

**And when the user adds a new record or clicks a new record, it should show the actual decrypted text like this:**

[image]

I need the **data at the source should be saved as an encrypted value** and not just hidden in the front end.

I think the solution is simple :). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Storing personal sensitive information has significant legal implications.  Rather than relying on free advice from a public website (which will be well meaning but potentially ill-informed), I suggest you seek professional advice.  This will protect yourself, your employer and the people who have trusted you with their personal data.  You need to consider the storage of the data, the transmission of the data from database to app and secure access to the app.  Also audit and access trails.  And probably more: I am not an expert.

Comment: @Limey thanks for the comment and I totally agree. In this case, the data is already stored on a secure network and the Shiny app is not open to the internet. The requirement to encrypt is an added security feature and is needed for now for a proof of concept.